# Python: Replace, rstrip() not able to remove newlines

Tags: python, replace, newline

I've got a spreadsheet of information (UTF-8 CSV file being read in by the csv module) that contains information for a large number of products that need to go into an inventory db. I'm trying to setup descriptions from newlined rows of text to a html list tags.

The issue I'm having is that the following lines fail to replace the newline character in the string:

```
line[2] = "<ul><li>" + line[2]
line[2].replace('\n', '</li><li>')
line[2] += "</li></ul>"
```

The string continues to contain newline characters even when the second line is replaced by:

```
line[2] = line[2].rstrip()
```

What is going on, and what am I messing up? =)

Answer (score 10):

From python manual

> **str.replace(old, new[, count])**
>   ***Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new***. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

As you can see, it doesn't replace "in place", instead, try:

```
line[2] = "<ul><li>" + line[2]
line[2] = line[2].replace('\n', '</li><li>')
line[2] += "</li></ul>"
```

Comment: I feel like an incredible idiot, and am eternally grateful to you. Thanks!

Comment: More to the point, python strings are immutable, so nothing is done to them "in place".

Comment: @James Christie Glad to help. Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Replace isn't in place.

So do

```
line[2] = "<ul><li>" + line[2].replace('\n', '</li><li>') + "</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to [escape](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape)!

```
escaped = cgi.escape(line[2].rstrip()).replace("\n", "</li><li>")
line[2] = "<ul><li>%s</li></ul>" % escaped
```

Str.replace returns a *copy* instead of modifying in-place, and rstrip with no argument will strip all trailing whitespace.  Since this is for HTML and trailing whitespace probably won't include something like "\n \n ", that probably doesn't matter to you, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: -1 """Str.replace ... with no argument will strip all trailing whitespace. """ Utter codswallop.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Meant rstrip; but that's still a deceptive way to quote it.

Comment: "deceptive"?? I'd call it "omitting words that are irrelevant to the comment, and inserting an ellipsis, as is proper, to show that text was omitted". In other words: you said that str.replace would with no argument strip all trailing whitespace. I'd also like to point out that the original text was easily perusable about a quarter of a screen-height away. What deception did you imagine that I was perpetrating??